# Tumblr: Content Overlaps Fixed Header?

Tags: html, css

I was able to code a fixed header into my Tumblr blog: http://artsypancake.tumblr.com/

The header works fine on my home page and it overlaps all of the posts, which is the intended effect. However, the content on my custom pages runs over my header when I scroll down. Example: http://artsypancake.tumblr.com/aboutme This is confusing that it only occurs with the custom pages that I've made.

Also, I've tried increasing the z-index for the header, but it doesn't make any difference on the custom page posts.

Here's the CSS for the header:

```
#topbar {
z-index: 999;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 27px;
text-align: center;
background-color: {color:Top Bar Background};
border-bottom: 3px solid {color:Top Bar Border};
}

#topbar a {
position: relative;
font-family: text me one;
color: {color:Top Bar Text};
background-color: {color: Top Bar Text Background};
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 9px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
top: 7px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#topbar a:hover {
background-color: {color:Top Bar Text Hover BG};
color: {color:Top Bar Text Hover};
}
```

CSS for the content:

```
.entry {
position: relative;
width: 500px;
background-color: {color:Entries};
border: 2px solid {color:Entries Border};
margin-bottom: -30px;
margin-top: 55px;
margin-left: 400px;
padding: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And the HTML for both the header and the entries, which are right next to each other:

```
<div id="topbar">...</div></div>
<div class="entry">...</div></div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comet! The problem would be that on your custom pages, the header is a child of `.leftbg` while on the main page the header is a peer of everything else. `#topbar` has a z-index of 999, but that only affects its peers (In this case, the .entries). To see this, inspect the element `#topbar` on a custom page and then on your home page. In the html, the header is either placed with other entries (so that z-index:999 places the header above the other content) or as a child of .leftbg, which has a default z-index of "auto".

To fix this, add a `z-index:1;` to `#leftbg`. While you could change the z-index of .entry to -1, that might break something else as I'm not super familiar with tumblr's layout.

On another note, I'd like to suggest disabling autoplay on your musicplayer. It's generally not a good thing to have autoplaying content when the user might not expect something to play.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This has completely made my day! (Frustrating that it was something as simple as that, but I wouldn't have been able to figure it out otherwise!) Thank you again! I also disabled the autoplay. :)